# find all $ a \in \mathbb{R}$?

Tags: real-analysis

> find  all $a \in \mathbb{R}$ such that   if $f$  is  any contnious   function on $[1,3]$  with  $\int_{1}^{ 3}f(x) dx= 1$ , then  there  exist  some  $x_0 \in (1,3)$  with $f(x_0) = a$

## My attempt :

I take $f(x) = \frac{x}{4}$  then  $\int_{1}^{ 3}f(x) dx= 1$

It  is given that  $x_0 \in (1,3)$  and we  have   $f(x) = \frac{x}{4}$

so  $'a'$  will be   $\frac{1.1 }{4}, \frac{1.2}{ 4},............,\frac{2.9}{4}$

Is its  true ?

Comment: Don't forget that $f$ is any continuous function, so consider the function $f(x)=\frac{1}{2}$. Shouldn't $a=\frac{1}{2}$ ?

Comment: okss@FareedAbiFarraj but  why not  $a= 1.2 /4$ ?

Comment: @jasmine Because for $f(x)=\frac12$ you don't have $x_0\in(1,3)$ with $f(x_0)=\frac{1.2}4$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since $f$ is any continuous function, with the condition that $\displaystyle\int_1^3 f(x) dx=1$, then $f(x)=\frac{1}{2}$ is an example of such a function.

So there must be some $x_0 \in (1,3)$ such that $f(x_0)=a$ but since this $f$ is a constant function then $\forall x\in (1,3)$, $f(x)=\frac{1}{2}$ thus $a=\frac{1}{2}$

It remains to prove that for any other function with these condition we can find an $x_0\in (1,3)$ such that $f(x_0)=\frac{1}{2}$, we can see this clearly by knowing the integral gives us the area under the curve, if the function gets below the horizantal line $y=\frac{1}{2}$ then for sure in some other point the curve will be above this line in order for the area to stay equal to $1$; which means that definetly at some point $x_0 \in (0,3)$ we will have $f(x_0)=\frac{1}{2}$

Comment: More precisely : the mean value theorem for integrals can be applied to any function on the interval to get the desired conclusion

Answer (score 1):

Find a non-trivial continuous function $f: [1,2] \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ such that $\int_1^2 f(x) d\text{x} = 0$ and $f(1) = f(2) = 0$ (a spike function would do, for example), then extend $f$ to $[1,3]$ such that $\int_1^3 f(x)d\text{x} = 1$, for example by having $f(x) = 2(x-2)$ for $x \in [2,3]$. This proves that the set consists of the whole $\mathbb{R}$.